# Wordpress or Custom? (Complicated/Long, Kinda)

Tags: database, wordpress, caching, pageload

This was probably asked before a few times, but I have a few questions that could seem, well, noobish. I have to apologize in advance if any of the questions I'm asking seem mediocre.

I'm starting a "random thought blog" project, with a few friends. I'm mainly the geek guy behind the project, though I'm expected to contribute every now and then with a few posts.

I've finished designing the theme, it's the typical blog style ish template and layout, can be easily integrated into any CMS.

The part that I found myself stuck with is the platform. The last time I started a project was back when phpBB 3 was still new. My experience with WordPress back then was, well, less than good.

My main thought was "We're about articles, purely, if we use media it'll be minimal. Code your own, Wordpress is bloated". I especially remember the caching issues with Wordpress, though I'm unsure what was the exact problem back then, to be specific, Wordpress had slow loading speeds (per page).

I started planning the platform, files structure, database structure, and so on, however, I found that the project, even though it's supposed to be minimalist, it's completely huge.

To give an idea, this is the basic database structure that I've come up with so far (Excuse obvious mistakes)

> User:
>   - id
>   - username
>   - public name
>   - email
>   - password
>   - birth date
>   - gender
>   - country
>   - avatar
>   - avatarUrl
>   - registrationDate
>   - displayContent
>   - group_id
>   - ip
>   - sessionToken
>   - sessionTime
>   - lastLogin
>   - loginAttempts
>   - isTrashed
>   - isBanned
>   - isFlagged
>   - isRestricted
>
> Group:
>   - id
>   - groupName
>   - groupColor
>   - groupIcon
>   - avatarEnable
>   - remoteAvatarEnable
>   - isAdmin
>   - addPost
>   - editPost
>   - trashPost
>   - deletePost
>   - editUser
>   - trashUser
>   - deleteUser
>   - addGroup
>   - editGroup
>   - trashGroup
>   - deleteGroup
>   - addPage
>   - editPage
>   - deletePage
>   - viewLogs
>   - isTrashed
>
> Category:
>   - id
>   - categoryName
>   - categoryIcon
>   - categoryColor
>   - isRecommend
>   - worthNotice
>   - sfw
>   - isTrashed
>
> Post:
>   - id
>   - title
>   - content
>   - authorName
>   - authorId
>   - date
>   - sfw
>   - category
>   - like
>   - dislike
>   - isTrashed
>   - lastEditedDate
>
> Comments
>   - id
>   - userid
>   - email
>   - website
>   - username
>   - content
>   - ip
>   - date
>   - postId
>
> Banned
>   - id
>   - isGuest
>   - userId
>   - username
>   - banDate
>   - startDate
>   - endDate
>   - isPermanent
>   - ip
>   - ipBanned
>
> Website
>   - domain
>   - offline
>   - allowLogin
>   - seoUrl
>   - enableCaptcha
>   - captchaKey
>   - shareButtons
>   - globalNotice
>   - noticeType
>   - displayNotice
>   - notepad
>   - displayAvatars
>   - displayRemoteAvatars
>   - defaultUserAvatar
>   - defaultGroupIcon
>   - defaultCategoryIcon
>   - pageIcon
>   - allowRemoteLogin
>   - allowLocalComments
>   - disqusKey
>
> Pages
>   - id
>   - name
>   - createdBy
>   - lasteditedBy
>   - date
>   - pageIcon
>   - lastUpdatedDate
>   - displayInCategory
>
> Logs
>   - id
>   - entryBy
>   - ip
>   - eventType
>   - eventName
>   - eventId

As you can see, at the early structure, it's a mess. Even if I go through the structure and end up with the perfect list for the project, this, while creating the list, really felt like a big blow of "that is one big wheel you're reinventing there!".

My concerns:
- Wordpress is obviously a well established and maintained platform, however, how does it scale for say, caching and minimalist usage? (backend)
- Stability, I've seen many users that still use the 3.9.4? version, last of its milestones in version 3, I think. My assumption was they basically figured "It's stable by now, I won't have to worry about updates much".
- I hate updating code every two weeks, I really do. Which is one of the major concerns, that if I use Wordpress, I'll be stuck updating it very often. Do they release minor milestones often?

I know it sounds bad, worrying about something like updates, because it's the one advice any geek would give (Always stay up to date).

My last concern, how does it scale in resources for shared hosting? ie: Number of queries performed per typical post page. Caching? Database Caching?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is really versatile and can be a really powerful platform for all kinds of projects. People are able to run not only blogs, but ecommerce, membership, forums and all different kinds websites on it.

I come of a background that I have managed Wordpress websites with over 1 million pageviews on a multiple server setup, but also optimized a lot of small websites on shared hosting environments. You just need to know how to set it up properly on "hostile" envoirnments like high volume, bad hosting, etc. Great thing is: most starters will not have to deal with it.

Wordpress is now on version 4.2.1 and usually minor versions come up every 2-3 weeks and major ones around every 3 months. Keeping updated is really painless and for most tech unsavvy users you can simply "leave it there" and it will update itself eventually. For users that want more control or know what they are doing, first thing I'd suggest is turning off automatic updates. But there is the downside: you have to update eventually, specially to avoid all kinds of exploits that might show up.

The platform itself can scale really well. The biggest problem you'll find on the way is actually your webserver. Most high-volumes website I had to "save from slow loading" were done in the server-side instead of the WP-side.

But you can of course optimize it and usually what I do, specially for shared hosting setups:

- Use a good cache plugin. [WP-Super-Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) is a really good one and it's easy to setup. I like [W3-Total-Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/), it has a lot of options and gives you a good control on all cache things. Both are great plugins and are being well maintained for years. I'm not entering the eternal discussion on which is better or faster, both will work fine no matter which you choose.
- Keep a clean code and that follow [wordpress coding standards](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards). This might seem obvious, but there are a LOT of bad coded themes out there. Themes that have all kind of flaws, like hitting the database directly (which can cause database cache bypass), non sanitized forms and inputs, etc.
- Use a CDN. It can make loading all theme assets (JS, CSS and Images) faster. For starters it's not hard to set up an Amazon S3 bucket and use it as a CDN, and it's also free, considering that most starters will not need to use all free-tier for Storage and Bandwidth that AWS gives you.
- I do recommend using [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) as an extra layer of cache and CDN. The free version is really good and solves your problem. Some hosting companies enforce the usage of Cloudflare or any cache plugin to avoid problems with cliends with bad WP code.

These are mostly optimization tips, but out-the-box Wordpress will work just fine. Give it a try at least. Hope this was helpful and clear.

Comment: Thank you, I came to the same conclusion. It made no sense recoding a full system when there is a fully stable and established platform available.

Really appreciate the examples you've included, I never tried that level of caching (GET query pages into HTML), I'll do some heavy simulations to see the creation/call resources usage.

My friend suggested that I should start off with a VPS, I'm considering that as well.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. I only suggest going with VPS if you really want to play around with customizing stuff that you couldn't on a shared server. If you are just putting a blog online and don't want to mess around with stuff like I have mentioned, you can go without problems on a shared server. Hope you enjoy WP!